# Manwha where the female lead is returned to the past and the prince "died" in the first life

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I believe that the female lead returns to the past when she was young. At some point she goes to some sort of park and runs into who I believe (based on context clues) is the prince. Pretty sure he was blonde. The female lead mentions (maybe in her head) how the prince dies in the future and she didn't know the boy she met was him. She continued to see the kinda sick boy in the park.